# Can anyone give a simple example such as construction within natural number set for pi-system/π-system?

Tags: measure-theory

In mathematics, a [π-system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi-system) (or pi-system) on a set Ω is a collection P of certain subsets of Ω, such that

> - P is non-empty.
> - A ∩ B ∈ P whenever A and B are in P.
>
> That is, P is a non-empty family of subsets of Ω that is closed under
>   finite intersections.

To illustrate this, I am trying to find a concrete example.

let $(A_n)_{n=2}^\infty$ denote the sequence of sets $A_n$

where $A_n$ is the set of primes $\le n (n\ge 2)$.

$A_2=\{2\},\ A_3=\{2,3\},A_4=A_3,A_5=\{2,3,5\},...$

is it possible to construct a π-system based on above?

Comment: Due to $A_n \subset A_{n+1}$ for any $n \in \mathbb N$, then for any $m, n\in \mathbb  
 N$, $m<n$ we have $A_m \cap A_n = A_m$, so the collection $ \{A_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is a $\pi-$ system

Comment: @DominikKutek Thanks man! Please mv your comments to answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to $A_n$ being the set of all prime numbers $\le n$, We clearly have, that for any $m,n \in \mathbb N$ such that $m<n$ it holds that $A_m \subset A_n$ (they may be equal). Since that, we have then $A_m \cap A_n = A_m$. So $\mathcal P = \{ A_n \}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is a $\pi -$system. (It is non-empty for obvious reason)